# Database-design: multiple tables & foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

This is my first post here. I've tried to look up at other topics, but haven't find anything that matches my request.
[image]
I have three tables (central, development, production) in my MySQL database. Central is my parent table and there are many columns that I would like to have on my child tables (development & production). Why am I doing it? It's because I don't want to share the whole content of central (share all the columns of this table) with different users of this server. Let's say that I have a column called "Name" in Central, I want that all the users accessing "development" and "production" to see the "Name" in these tables and be able to add information as well. So, they (users that are accessing development & production) would be able to change the column "Name" and also work on other fields that are not included in the "Central", which is my parent table. Please see the attached diagram.

Thanks very much.

Comment: There are two different questions here - One is read access to columns in "Central", you can typically control this with views. The other is write access to specific columns, this kind of sounds like you just want to have a couple of sandbox tables with the same structure that users can write to as they please. There's nothing inherently wrong with that, but depending on your use case there might be something very wrong with it. Can't say without more details.

Comment: I'm not following your description of what you want to do at all.   And just asking "any thoughts?" is far too broad.   Is there a specific problem or question you have?

Comment: Thanks guys. @Error_2646: I agree. I'm going to read the "views" documentation now. What do you mean by "something very wrong". Is it related to data redundancy (I've added a simple diagram to try to explain what I'm doing) ? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information the following seems like what you want.  I am assuming that changes in "central" are reflected in "development" and "production" and vice versa.  I am assuming that the users x, y, and z are database users, not application users and that they already exist.  I'm assuming your database name is "app".

```
CREATE VIEW development AS
SELECT id, name, investment, inventory FROM central;

CREATE VIEW production AS
SELECT id, name, address, revenue FROM central;

GRANT all ON app.central TO 'x'@'somehost';
GRANT all ON app.development TO 'x'@'somehost';
GRANT all ON app.development TO 'y'@'somehost';
GRANT all ON app.production TO 'x'@'somehost';
GRANT all ON app.production TO 'z'@'somehost';
```

Comment: Thanks, Rob!! Solved!! Have a great weekend!

Comment: If this solution worked for you, would you mind marking this answer as correct?  Thank you.